# jQuery DataTables - Show entries menu and filtering is not working

Tags: ajax, jsp, datatables

I created table in JSP file and it is showing all records without filtering and "Show 10 entries" count. My code is shown below.

When I searched other answers, the solution is to set `iDisplayLength`. But this didn't work for me.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function searchfiles() {

    $('#fileLoader').DataTable({
        "bProcesing" : true,
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "iDisplayLength" : 10,
        destroy: true,  //reinitializing of the data table
        "aoColumns" : [ {
            "sTitle" : "Rate Files",
            "mData" : "filePath",
        } ],
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": 0,
            "data": "download_link",
            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
              return '<a href="'+data+'">'+data.split('.pdf')[0]+'</a>';
            }
          } ],
        "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            aoData.push({
                "name" : "hotel",
                "value" : $("#hotel").val()
            });
            aoData.push({
                "name" : "season",
                "value" : $("#season").val()
            });
            aoData.push({
                "name" : "market",
                "value" : $("#market").val()
            });
            aoData.push({
                "name" : "sheetDate",
                "value" : $("#sheet_date").val()
            });
            $.ajax({
                "type" : "POST",
                "url" : "searchfiles",
                "data" : aoData,
                "success" : fnCallback
            });
        },
    });
}
</script>


<table id="fileLoader" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rate Files</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

You have server-side processing enabled with `"bServerSide": true`. In this mode searching, filtering and pagination should be done on the server-side.

Most likely your server-side script (`searchfiles`) isn't programmed to do so, that's why you don't see ordering/filtering/pagination working.

With `bServerSide: false` or omitted you can still get data from the server via Ajax but searching/filtering and pagination will be performed by jQuery DataTables on the client side.

See [manual](http://datatables.net/manual/data) for more information on processing modes.

> **SOLUTION**

Remove `"bServerSide": true` to enable client-side processing.

Comment: Thanks,  But Iam getting data from server. So I can't remove    "bServerSide": true      But I will set iTotalDisplayRecords and iTotalRecords into json object in server side

Comment: @Rosh, `bServerSide: true` doesn't mean you cannot get data from from the server, it means that server will be responsible for searching/filtering and pagination. With `bServerSide: false`, you can still get data from the server but searching/filtering and pagination will be done by jQuery DataTables on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I enable client side processing.